# Problem with 2560x1440 resolution Ubuntu 18.04 Intel graphics driver

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a new Dell Optiplex 7060. Everything works fine, except when I set the monitor's resolution to the full 2560x1440. Then I do get the right screen resolution, but my screen blanks out every ~ 10 seconds for roughly 1 second. Lower resolutions work without problem.

According to my system settings I have an Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2) graphics card, and my monitor is connected through DisplayPort.

Any ideas what I could try? Do you need more information?

Thanks, Jeroen

Answer (score 1):

Update:

So I started to make random changes in my setup, and it seems that changing the monitor cable solved the problem.

Before, I had a cable DisplayPort (computer) to Mini-DisplayPort (monitor), and I now switched to DisplayPort to DisplayPort. It looks like that solved the problem, whatever it was. It almost certainly cannot have been a physical problem with the cable, because the very same cable and monitor worked fine with the same version of Ubuntu on my previous Dell desktop.

I know this is not very insightful, but maybe it could be helpful for someone else who runs into the same problem.